# App Engine db.model reference question

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I get at the Labels data from within my Task model?

```
class Task(db.Model):
  title = db.StringProperty()

class Label(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Tasklabel(db.Model):
  task = db.ReferenceProperty(Task)
  label = db.ReferenceProperty(Label)
```

creating the association is no problem, but how can I get at the labels associated with a task like:

```
task = Task.get('...')
for label in task.labels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want a [ListProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#Lists) on Task like this to do a many-to-many?

```
class Label(db.Model)
   name = db.StringProperty()

   @property
   def members(self):
      return Task.gql("WHERE labels = :1", self.key())

class Task(db.Model)
   title = db.StringProperty();
   labels = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

Then you could do

```
foo_label = Label.gql("WHERE name = 'foo'").get()
task1 = Task.gql("WHERE title = 'task 1'").get()
if foo_label.key() not in task1.labels:
  task1.labels.append(foo_label.key())
task1.put()
```

There's a thorough article about modeling entity relationships on [Google code](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html).  I stole the code above from this article.

Comment: that may be the solution, I thought I could do it without

Comment: Mind if I ask why?  The appengine datastore seems to make it easy to do away with the join tables like TaskLabel that are common in RDBMS.

Comment: I see that using the listproperty may be the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with your current datamodel:

```
taskObject = db.Query(Task).get()
for item in taskObject.tasklabel_set:
        item.label.name
```

Or you could remove the Label class and just do a one-to-many relationship between Task and TaskLabel:

```
class Task(db.Model):
        title = db.StringProperty()

class TaskLabel(db.Model):
        task = db.ReferenceProperty(Task)
        label = db.StringProperty()
```

Then

```
taskObject = db.Query(Task).get()
for item in taskObject.tasklabel_set:
        item.label
```

Here is a tip from the Google article on modeling relationships in the datastore

> By defining it as a ReferenceProperty, you have created a property that can only be assigned values of type 'Task'. Every time you define a reference property, it creates an implicit collection property on the referenced class. By default, this collection is called _set. In this case, it would make a property Task.tasklabel_set.

The article can be found  [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html).

I also recommend playing around with this code in the interactive console on the dev appserver.

Comment: how can I "play around with this code in the interactive console on the dev appserver"? Django has one, but I haven't found one for GAE.

Comment: When you have the dev_appserver running on your local machine you can go to http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive and test snippets of code there. You'll have to provide the usual import statements for your code to work. Type your code and hit 'run program' at the bottom.